# Fatal error when deploying Codeigniter: Unable to open core/Codeigniter.php

Tags: codeigniter

I am having this fatal error and warning on my first Codeigniter attempt:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/core/CodeIgniter.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear\') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\index.php on line 202

What would cause this? I'm not sure where to begin to look.

Comment: please post what is on "C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\index.php on line 202"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using the **index.php** as the default index page of your project?

if not use **.htaccess** file and also edit the **config.php** file in the `/project/config` folder

make sure about all your routes are declared correctly in your configuration files like: **routes.php** etc.

Comment: thanks KAsh for the reply. Bt can u clarify wot is .htaccess file, i didnt find smthing like dat in ma CI folder...

Comment: you have to add it externally in your project folder
this file contains some information like:
`RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /project_folder_name

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]`

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal change permission of your folder project :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 project_path/
```

I hope that's will be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /project_folder_name

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

the .htaccess looks like this.